# How to generate FormArray items?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I need to create FormArray items from array. But I have error in console:

```
ERROR
Error: Converting circular structure to JSON
--> starting at object with constructor 'FormArray'
| property 'controls' -> object with constructor 'Array'
| index 0 -> object with constructor 'FormControl'
--- property '_parent' closes the circle
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zacdyq

Answer (score 0):

At the line 32:

```
childs: cloneAbstractControl(this.childs)
```

make the circular structure. If you replace this line to this:

```
childs: cloneAbstractControl(this.fb.control(item))
```

You don't make any circular references.

Comment: This solution gives another structure. I want to have double array, as I write in comment.